# How to set invocation count during execution for test method that uses data provider in TestNg &java/ Kotlin?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider, invocation

I did refer this link and understood about `IAnnotationTransformer`.

I have a scenario where I have parameterized data with data provider. Need to run test with certain data for N number of times using invocation Count which.

How do I leverage the transform?

```
@DataProvider(name = "loginData", parallel = false)
fun loginDataProvider(): MutableIterator<String> {
    val loginTestData: ArrayList<String> = ["abc", "def", "xyz"]
    return loginTestData.iterator()
}
    
@Test(dataProvider = "loginData")
fun funloginTest(loginDetails: String){
    print("The value of $loginDetails")
}
```

How do I run this test 4 times for the parameter "def"?

Ideally I want to get the `invocationCount` before every run for the test case from an external source like a json and run the test N number of times for specific data

I tried looking at many `invocationCount` and `IAnnotationTransformer` and couldn't find the exact answer. Any idea or code snippet to solve the problem can help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IAnnotationTransformer` doesn't seems to work in this case.
I suggest to modify the behaviour of DataProvider method instead.

1. create a mapping of value need to override invocation count.
   e.g. `{ "funloginTest" : { "def" : 4 } }`
2. Inside `loginDataProvider`, we can use the test method name(Referring to [document of DataProvider](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)) to see which data need to have different invocation count.

```kotlin
class RepeatedRunTest {
    // TODO read it from json
    private val testToCaseInvocationCount = mapOf("funloginTest" to mapOf("def" to 4))

    @DataProvider(name = "loginData", parallel = false)
    fun loginDataProvider(testMethod: Method): MutableIterator<String> {
        println(testMethod.name)
        val loginTestData: Array<String> = arrayOf("abc", "def", "xyz")
        return loginTestData.map { testData ->
            List(
                // repeat if needed
                testToCaseInvocationCount
                    .getOrDefault(testMethod.name, emptyMap())
                    .getOrDefault(testData, 1)
            ) { testData }
        }
            .flatten().toMutableList().listIterator()
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "loginData")
    fun funloginTest(loginDetails: String) {
        print("The value of $loginDetails")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer/. logic worked. Basically adding the same test data was added N number of times inside the data provider lister iterator